# Macro definitions used in the string variable

Tags: c++, c

I want to achieve this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STR_HELLO_LEN 10
#define str(opt) STR_###opt##_LEN

int main(int argc, char **argv)

{
    char *tmp = "hello";
    int y=str(tmp);  // y = STR_HELLO_LEN,but is STR_tmp_LEN

    return(0);
}
```

y = STR_HELLO_LEN,but is STR_tmp_LEN

Comment: Why don't you write an inline function for it?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible to do. All the macros are resolved at compile time. The "hello" only really exists at runtime.

Comment: thanks, i thank so,   there is a better way to achieve that?

Comment: You'll have to use functions. You can declare it as an inline function using `inline` keyword before the function.

Comment: @Krishna_Sp, if it is viable to declare `tmp` as an array of `char` instead of a pointer (e.g. `char tmp[10] = "hello";`), then wherever that array declaration is in scope, you can use the `sizeof` operator to get the number of bytes in the array.  That's not what you asked for, but it looks like it might serve your purposes.

Comment: I didn't quite understand. What would you achieve with that ?